# Block LDAP users after x failed log in attempts

Tags: c#, windows, security, active-directory, ldap

I got an LDAP set so I can store users on AD and authenticate them. I use the code below to validate their credentials and it seems to be working fine for that purpose; but I'm hitting a wall when trying to prevent brute force attacks, I tried to use Active Directory settings so I could let it control that for me, blocking the user after X failed attemps. Problem is that after an attempt to login with an invalid password the badPwdCount field on LDAP is still set to 0 and, no matter how many times I make failed log in attempts, the user is never blocked.

Below you can see the code I'm using to authenticate users in LDAP:

```
    private void TryAuthenticate(string password, string fullUserName)
    {
        LdapDirectoryIdentifier ide = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(this.host, Convert.ToInt32(this.port));
        LdapConnection con = new LdapConnection(ide);

        con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = (secure == "1");

        con.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
        con.AutoBind = false;
        con.Bind(GetNetworkCredentials(password, fullUserName));

        con.Dispose();
        con = null;
    }
```

Do you guys got any thoughts about this? I'm stuck here.

NOTE: I know I can manually handle this but I'd rather have AD do this for me.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to DoS your own users? Because that's what you're asking. Use CAPTCHA or Proof of Work

Comment: I see your point, but it is not my call. In fact this question came out with the architecture team and they opted to make it like this. I'm pretty much stuck with this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going on, so I post it here for anyone interested: You need to open ADSI Edit and connected to the ADAM instance, expand Configuration container and drill down to CN=Directory Service node, right click on it to display its Properties dialog box, locate msDS-Other-Settings attribute, and click on Edit command button. In the Multi-valued String Editor dialog box you should see ADAMDisablePasswordPolicies, set its value to 0 and that's it. If ADAMDisablePasswordPolicies is set 1 it will ignore the password settings and it won't block the user no matter what.